# Cannot launch my docfx project due to pathing problem

Tags: docfx

I have a DocFx project folder which contains all the correct files to host the project.
On my laptop, I'm able to use the code `docfx docfx.json --serve` to host the project on my localhost completely fine. However on my PC it errors out.

I'm syncing my files using GitHub, so the files / file locations are identical.
Also Initially it worked on my PC, then it stopped...

The error I'm getting is this:

> [20-10-10 04:54:46.403]Error:System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Windows\System32\docfx_project\obj.cache\build\4t5lswwe.fue\dynp2fa1.gsl'.
> at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)

[Complete Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chER5.png)

Current Directory:

> PS C:\Users\aiden\Documents\GitHub\TAFE.2020.S2.SMALL.GROUP.PROJECT\docfx_project>

As you can see, my current directory is the project directory. However the error message states it's trying to pull docfx data files from within' system32. The files it is trying to pull are within' my docfx project.

Since it cannot find the files in system32, it errors out.

Anyone know how or why this is happening??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No idea why, but the version of Docfx (project files) on my laptop were not syncing properly to my PC.

I realized this, deleted the version on my PC (outdated one) and copied it over.

There must have been something messed up in my old Docfx project because as soon as I opened the new one, it worked.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I moved the DocFx project around between folders; after that, the problem ocurred. I think, it is something with the cache of DocFx (incremental builds)

I solved it with

```
docfx docfx.json --force
```